# assembly logical shift left solidity don't work

Tags: solidity

```
function shift(int val) returns(int) {
    int res;
    assembly {
        let m := mload(0x40)
        mstore(m, shl(2, val))
        mstore(0x40, add(m, 0x20))
        res := mload(m)
    }

    return res;
}
```

Documentation
shl(x, y) //logical shift left y by x bits

Result always 0;
In testrPC it don't work at all.

Geth version: 1.8.10-stable
OS: ubuntu 16.04
Go version: 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receive this warning when I compile your code:

```
browser/Untitled3.sol:8:23: Warning: The "shl" instruction is only available for
Constantinople-compatible VMs. You are currently compiling for "byzantium", where it will
be interpreted as an invalid instruction.

            mstore(m, shl(2, val))
                      ^---------^
```

It looks like there's a plan to add this instruction in the Constantinople fork, which hasn't happened yet: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/145. For now, no such opcode exists.